# compute optical flow using blender

Tags: vector, blender

I am using blender to render a set of images with motion at different exposures. I have enabled the "vector" pass during rendering and I am aware of the blender format vector:

R: pixel displacement in X from current frame to previous frame

G: pixel displacement in Y from current frame to previous frame

B: pixel displacement in X from current frame to next frame

A: pixel displacement in Y from current frame to next frame

But I am a bit confused as to do I need to disable the other passess like "Z" and "Combined" during this process. And also if I take an image from the set, does the RGBA channels give me straight the vector information of that image with respect to the previous one or the next one.

thanks a lot,

kangkan